# Error al llamar funciones

Tags: c++

El programa consiste en acertar la loteria y luego acertar otro premio.

El problema es al declarar la funcion felicitaciones(). Al llamar a esta desde el main me da error y si la llamo al final de la funcion loteria(), no se ejecuta pero no salta error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

bool loteria();
void felicitaciones(bool premio,bool bonus);

int main()
{
    loteria();
    return 0;
}

bool loteria()
{
    int num,num2;
    bool premio,bonus;
    cout<<"Introduce un numero del 1 al 9:";
    cin >> num;

    if(num==8)
    {
        cout <<endl<< "Premio"<<endl;
        premio=true;
    }else
    {
        cout << "Nada";
        return 0;
    }

    cout << "Si acierta de nuevo se lleva un bonus:";
    cin >> num2;

     if(num2==1)
    {
        cout << endl<<"Bonus"<<endl;
        bonus=true;
        return premio,bonus;
    }else
    {
        cout << "Nada";
        bonus=false;
        return premio,bonus;
    }
    felicitaciones(premio,bonus);
}

void felicitaciones(bool premio, bool bonus)
{
    if(premio==true && bonus==true)
    {
        cout << "Usted es un afortunado";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "No tiene mucha suerte";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código tiene algún que otro fallo:

1. No puedes poner esa especie de doble *return*, ya que sólo va a devolver una sola cosa. Si necesitas devolver más de un elemento, te aconsejo que uses otro tipo de estructura, bien un *TAD*, o bien, que uno sea devuelto, y el otro, un parámetro pasado por referencia, etc..
2. No tiene sentido que la función *loteria()* tenga valor de retorno, porque en tu caso no llegas a usarlo.
3. No se ejecuta la función *felicitaciones* porque si te fijas la función *loteria * tiene un valor de retorno si cumple la 2ª condición `(num2==1)` y sino, dará el retorno la siguiente sentencia `else`. Ahora bien, tu código sigue, pero no tiene sentido ya que no se llegará a ejecutar ninguna sentencia después de la sentencia return.

Precisamente a nivel sintáctico y lógico la función felicitaciones es correcta. Una posible implementación es la siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void loteria(bool &premio, bool &bonus); // las variables son pasadas por referencia 
void felicitaciones(bool premio,bool bonus);

int main()
{
    bool premio = false;
     bool bonus = false;
    loteria(premio, bonus);
    felicitaciones (premio, bonus);
}

void loteria(bool &premio, bool &bonus)
{
    int num,num2;
    cout<<"Introduce un numero del 1 al 9:";
    cin >> num;

    if(num==8)
    {
        cout <<endl<< "Premio"<<endl;
        premio=true;
    }else
    {
        cout << "Nada";
    }

    cout << "Si acierta de nuevo se lleva un bonus:";
    cin >> num2;

     if(num2==1)
    {
        cout << endl<<"Bonus"<<endl;
        bonus=true;
    }else
    {
        cout << "Nada";
    }
}

void felicitaciones(bool premio, bool bonus)
{
    if(premio==true && bonus==true)
    {
        cout << "Usted es un afortunado";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "No tiene mucha suerte";
    }
}
```

Comment: Lo veo todo claro excepto una cosa. Que funcionalidad tiene el 'and' aqui--->&premio

Comment: Se emplea para pasar el parámetro por referencia y no por valor. Dicho de otro modo, que al cambiar el valor en premio y bonus dentro de la función loteria, también cambiará en las variables del método main, donde son pasadas por referencia a la función. He agregado un comentario para que otras personas puedan identificarlo

Comment: ¿Y si retornara premio y bonus al final de la funcion funcionaria?

Comment: Para devolver premio y bonus al final de la función, estamos hablando de devolver dos elementos. Te aconsejo que para eso, crees un struct con dos elementos, que al fin y al cabo, es crearte tu propio tipo de dato (un tipo de dato que contiene dos datos) y de esa forma puedas devolverlo en una sentencia return.

Comment: @Víctor "*Te aconsejo que para eso, crees un struct con dos elementos*" o que use algún objeto existente capaz de contener múltiples valores como `std::pair`, o una `std::tuple`, o un `std::initializer_list`...

Answer (score 3):

#### C++ no permite retorno múltiple de valores.

En tu función `loteria()` tienes retornos así:

```
return premio,bonus;
```

Lo que hace ese código es invocar el operador coma (`,`) sobre `premio` y `bonus`. El operador coma evalúa la primera expresión (`premio`), la descarta y ejecuta la segunda expresión (`bonus`) y devuelve dicha expresión. Así que tu orden de retorno es exactamente igual a:

```
return bonus;
```

#### Bueno, C++ si permite retorno múltiple de valores si sabes cómo hacerlo.

Si cambias tu función `bool loteria()` a `std::pair<bool, bool> loteria()` podrías devolver dos valores si tu sentencia de retorno es así:

```
return {premio,bonus};
//     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~^ <-- construye un std::pair<bool, bool>
```

Pero te obliga a que el retorno sea doble en todos los puntos de la función, así que tu `return 0;` cuando no se consigue premio debería ser así:

```
return {false,false};
//     ^~~~~~~~~~~~^ <-- construye un std::pair<bool, bool>
```

Puedes recoger el retorno de `bool loteria()` al estilo C++17:

```
int main()
{
    auto [premio, bonus] = loteria();
    return 0;
}
```

Si tu compilador aún no soporta C++17 puedes recoger el retorno así:

```
int main()
{
    auto estado = loteria();
    bool premio = estado.first, bonus = estado.second;
    return 0;
}
```